# Shoud I must delare global in python when i change list in function?

Tags: python, django

This is my code.

```
my_list = [{"id": 1, "data": "Python"},
           {"id": 2, "data": "Code"},
           {"id": 3, "data": "Learn"}]


def this():
    for index in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[index]["id"] == 2:
            del my_list[index]
            break
this()
print(my_list)

>>> [{'id': 1, 'data': 'Python'}, {'id': 3, 'data': 'Learn'}]
```

I can see that my_list[1] has removed.

But I have a problem.

I don't declare **global my_list** , but why I can change a list outside of function in function?

Comment: Because `global` is only required to *assign to a global variable in a function*, not mutate an object. In fact, assignment to a variable**never mutates an object**. The only thing required to mutate the object is to be able to reference it (and then use a mutator method)

Answer (score 0):

The variables that are declared in the global scope can be accessed from anywhere in the program. Global variables can be used inside any function. We can also change the global variable value inside the function.

But, if we declare a local variable with the same name as a global variable then the local scope will use the local variable.

If you want to use the global variable inside the local scope and assign a new value to that, then you will need to use the “global” keyword.

For more details visit: https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/python-variable-scope/